# Algolia Autocomplete and display in result page on enter key or submit

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, algolia, instantsearch

I am looking for a solution with Algolia in React. I have a search bar where I  am using autocomplete feature to load the result of products . Now when i click on submit button or Enter key i want to redirect to new result page where i want to display all the products with the available filters. As i seen most places it is using instantSearch where result loads on typing. Im looking for separate result page with filters and apply filter within the result page.